# Airflow:.AirflowException: Issues in reading JSON template variable

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

**Requirement**: I am trying to avoid using `Variable.get()` Instead use Jinja templated `{{var.json.variable}}`

I have defined the variables in JSON format as an example below and stored them in the secret manager as `snflk_json`

**snflk_json**

```
{
   "snwflke_acct_request_memory":"4000Mi",
   "snwflke_acct_limit_memory":"4000Mi",
   "schedule_interval_snwflke_acct":"0 12 * * *",
   "LIST" ::[
      "ABC.DEV","CDD.PROD"
   ]
}
```

**Issue 1:** Unable to retrieve schedule interval from the JSON variable

**Error :** Invalid timetable expression: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iterator expression.

Tried to use in the dag as below

```
 schedule_interval = '{{var.json.snflk_json.schedule_interval_snwflke_acct}}',
```

**Issue 2:**

I am trying to loop to get the task for each in LIST, I tried as below but in vain

```
with DAG(
            dag_id = dag_id,
            default_args = default_args,
            schedule_interval = '{{var.json.usage_snwflk_acct_admin_config.schedule_interval_snwflke_acct}}' ,
            dagrun_timeout = timedelta(hours=3),
            max_active_runs = 1,
            catchup = False,
            params = {},
            tags=tags
    ) as dag:    
    shares = '{{var.json.snflk_json.LIST}}'
    for s in shares:
        sf_tasks = SnowflakeOperator(
                        task_id=f"{s}" ,
                        snowflake_conn_id= snowflake_conn_id,
                        sql=sqls,
                        params={"sf_env": s},
                    )
```

**Error**

```
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 754, in __init__
    validate_key(task_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py", line 63, in validate_key
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The key '{' has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively
```

Comment: Add render_template_as_native_obj=True to your Dag definition.

Comment: @ozs I mentioned it in the WITH DAG , still i see an error for schedule_interval

Comment: What is your airflow version? It supported after 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is parsing the dag every few seconds (30 by default). so actually it runs the for loop on a string with value {{var.json.snflk_json.LIST}} and that why you get that error.

you should use DynamicTask (from ver 2.3) or put the code under Python task that creates tasks and execute the new tasks.